# Problems with fopen function on Mac

Tags: c++, c, macos, fopen

I'm making a simple application on Mac (OSX Mavericks, compiling with clang).
The problem is that when I try to open a file using the relative path, it doesn't work. It works if I use the absolute path.

For example, if I try : `fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");`

It returns `NULL`.

It only works if I use: `fp = fopen(" User/UserName/Project_folder/file.txt", "r");`
(project folder is the folder that I'm compiling in, and it has my file.txt)

The file is in the exactly same directory.

How I can solve this?

Also the same code has worked well some time ago, and now this and other code that uses the `fopen` show the same problem.

Comment: file.txt needs to be in the same director where you run your program from. See my post below.

Comment: does `fp = fopen("./file.txt", "r");` work?

Comment: @Andro47: Prepending `./` won't help; that's still a relative path.

Comment: fp = fopen("./file.txt", "r"); Don't help, now I understand better the problem, but I can't solve. If I run the compiled file using the terminal it find the file (the working directory is the same of the file).  But when I open it with a double click it run, but with a working directory that is different of the directory of the file. To be more precise it open using /user as a working directory. This appear here have few time. Few times ago I haven't this issue.

Comment: @BrenoRodrigues see my update below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `fopen` without full path, it uses the current working directory of the location where you ran the program from. So if your working directory (obtained by typing `pwd` in shell) *where you execute your program from* is `~/my_folder/` and `file.txt` happens to be in `~/my_folder/bin/` then even if your executable is inside `~/my_folder/bin/` it won't find `file.txt`. Because it will be looking for `~/my_folder/file.txt`.

So if you are running your program from a different directory than that of file.txt then you either have to provide absolute path or provide a path relative to the directory that you are running your program from.

For info on working directory see http://www.linfo.org/current_directory.html

**Update**

One workaround that can be used if you have access to the string array argument (`argv[]`) of `main` method. The first element of argv will contain the path (from working directory) that was used to execute your program. Following simple program simple prints that argument.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Path relative to the working directory is: %s\n", argv[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

This will print the relative path including the executable name. You can replace executable name with `file.txt` if that file is in the same location as executable. This way it will load in both scenarios: when run by double-clicking and also when run from command line by navigating to the location of the executable.

You may also have to take into account the possible `./` at the beginning of `argv[0]`. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Both are in the same directory, I know this. But now the file don't load more. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: When you type `pwd` in command line does it show the same path as that of file.txt?

Comment: The app when I open with a double click does not use the working directory that it is. How can I solve it? This issue appear here have few time.

Comment: When you run it by double click, youw working directory is the directory of binaries.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure, but I think that on macs the default directory in which the program searches for relative paths is not the current directory but the user directory. Try to put *file.txt* in this one.

(Note: I remember having a problem like this once, but I am not sure it was with fopen. Well, can't hurt to try...)

Comment: that's exactly what I've met

Answer (score -1):

You could try to init the pointer with writing.
So if the program cannot find the file, it should create a new one. That could help to understand whats happining.